# Windows Phone - Live Tile returns to home screen

Tags: windows, mobile, live, tile

Does anyone know of a way to suppress the automatic return to the home screen when creating a secondary tile? I'd like to have it created in the background and to stay in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't.  You could pop up a message box telling the user to position the tile and then press the back button to return to your app.  But that is all you can do.

I have an app that makes two tiles, and I tried and tried to make this work in the background.